# I have installed scrapy succefully why command not found?

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

```
qiao-lideMacBook-Pro:~ qiao-li$ pip3 freeze    
......    
**Scrapy==1.4.0**        
......    
qiao-lideMacBook-Pro:~ qiao-li$ scrapy version    
**-bash: scrapy: command not found**
```

Comment: where is the description of the problem

Comment: Did you just install it ? If you're in a virtualenv, you should source your .bashrc, restart your terminal, or equivalent

Comment: Please. format your question in appropriate way. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section if you need some help

Answer (score 0):

Check Scrapy installation using the following command. You are running a wrong command to test.

`python -c "import scrapy; print(scrapy.__version__)"`

Comment: I need to use this command `scrapy startproject  XXX`  but `-bash: scrapy: command not found`